# Unable to do wireless debugging (ADB) in android

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, usb-otg, adbwireless

I have a situation where I need to store some data on USB. There are some errors that occur when I try to attach USB to my android device. I tried to debug my app through ADB. Here is what I have done up till now.

1. I have downloaded the AndroidWiFiADB plugin.
2. I have connected my mobile by giving commands through the terminal.

   E:>adb connect 192.168.0.13:5555
   connected to 192.168.0.13:5555

   and it shows that my device is connected in the terminal.

   E:>adb devices
   List of devices attached
   0123456789ABCDEF        device
   192.168.0.13:5555       device
3. But when I press the AndroidWiFiADB icon I get the following message.

   "Unable to connect to device 'Signature_Touch'. Make sure that your computer 
    and your device is connected to the same WiFi network."

[image: When ever I click on connect it says "Unable to connect to device 'Signature_Touch'. Make sure that your computer and your device are connected to the same WiFi network.]

I have enabled all the possible options of wifi available in developers' options. 
[image]

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/69622418/236465 for Android 11+

Answer (score 7):

1. **Before connecting through WiFi you need to connect the device using USB** to authorize the PC in the device (Such thing can't be done through wifi).
2. Then using the terminal, **ping** the device's IP. Pinging must be successful.
3. Then restart ADB and connect to your device.

**Update**

Since Android 11, you can use Android studio BumbleBee to use built-in "Adb over wifi" feature

Comment: I have tried ping the device it shows some reply from device and statistics but it still does not work.

Comment: No need for a usb cable if you use the adb pair <ip>:<port> command and follow prompts for Pair device with pairing code in Wireless debugging on the device.

Comment: Great answer from an AFOL :) After connecting with the USB it started working immediately. Cannot thank you enough!

Answer (score 6):

Follow these below steps:

- Connect your phone to PC/Laptop with USB.
- Open terminal, go to your `AndroidSDK/platform-tools` local path and type `adb devices`. That will list down all connected devices.
- Type: `adb tcpip 5555`
- Type: `adb connect <your-ip-address>:5555`
- Type: `adb devices`. That will show your device that is connected wireless with your IP Address and Port.

Then, you can enjoy Wireless debugging.

**Note: You need to have same network on your PC/Laptop and on your phone.**

Comment: @J.Doe: which device you are using?

Comment: I have been using Huwaei Y 7 prime,Huwaei P 30, Samsung S 5 ,vertu signature touch and some other devices as well.

Comment: i am using phone data in pc .. it is not connecting

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ADB Wifi Connect](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9717-adb-wifi-connect/) to debug the android application via wifi. You can also find it from android studio plugins.

> You have to be in the same network to use wifi debugging.

May be help you.

Comment: I am already connect to my device in terminal. I am using same wifi that's why I am connected.

Answer (score 0):

Your Computer and Your Device should be connected to the same network. So that your device can be able to make a bridge connection with your computer.

Comment: Did you tried without using 5555 while making the connection.

Comment: yes I used 5555 port for connection the connection was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens that you need to connect your Android via USB first, in order to trigger the device key authorization dialog. Hope this helps someone.