# Unable to connect ADB over wifi in Home WLAN

Tags: android, macos, tcp, adb, wifi

I am trying to connect my android devices to ADB over wifi from my mac. I was able to start. I used the below commands to achieve so,

`adb tcpip 5555`

restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

`adb connect <DEVICE_IP>:5555`

after entering connect command there is no response for a few minutes and later tells `Operation timed out`
I am able to connect to ADB via wifi through the mobile hotspot, when I switch back to my WLAN the same happens. Is this is due to any firewall/restriction with my modem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If you device is using **Android 11+**, then

1. Enable the Wireless debugging option (in developer settings).
2. On the dialog that asks Allow wireless debugging on this network?, click Allow.
3. Select Pair device with pairing code. Take note of the pairing code, IP address, and port number displayed on the device (see [image](https://developer.android.com/studio/images/wireless-adb.png))
4. On your workstation, open a terminal and navigate to `android_sdk/platform-tools`.
5. Run `adb pair ipaddr:port`. Use the IP address and port number from step 4.

More details [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+).

However, your router might be filtering traffic between wifi connected devices. Check you router documentation or try another pair of devices (i.e. 2 computers) to verify whether it happens.