# Getting error while connect to adb (10061)

Tags: adb

**Hey!
For many days I am facing problems for adb,whenever I tries to connect adb it shows me error 10061**
Like this:

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1:58526
cannot connect 127.0.0.1:58526: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

Already tried almost all provided solutions on internet but none of them worked as my problem is different
I am not connecting to my mobile.
I am trying to connect with ip address provided in windows subsystem for android.
But every time I get this error and I am facing this adb error for last 2 months
Please Help
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It appears you're connecting locally within your machine. Did you make sure your firewall is not causing this to fail? I recommend posting some of the solutions you've found online and explaining why those did not work for you.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/69622418/236465

Comment: Thanks I will reply soon if it worked!

Comment: I tried after disabling all firewalls but it still not working