# ADB devices stuck authorizing

Tags: android, adb

I'm stuck in "authorizing" status on ADB. I can't bring the "USB debug authorization view" back. On the other hand my phone does says "USB debugging connected. Tap to turn off USB debugging".

```
❯ adb devices
List of devices attached
xxxxxxxx    authorizing
```

This used to work properly (for 2-3 years), I haven't changed my setup (same host, same physical device, same USB port, same cable). I updated OSX a few days ago so this may be related to this issue.

```
❯ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 31.0.3-7562133

❯ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.6.1
BuildVersion:   20G224
```

The mobile device is a `ONEPLUS A6013`, running on android 11.

I've tried several things:

1. unplug/replug the USB cable (changing cable/port)
2. restart both my machine and mobile
3. quit/join again the developper mode on my mobile
4. [revoking USB authorizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized) on my mobile
5. [removing private/public ADB keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55243629/1720199) on my laptop (I also tried completely recreating `~/.android`)
6. uninstalling/reinstalling all android build/platform tools (in android studio)
7. updating one plus' Oxygen OS

None of these allowed me to show the prompt asking for the USB debug authorization on my phone.

**EDIT**

We've also tried connecting another phone to my laptop (it didn't work either). We tried connecting my phone to another laptop and it worked as expected (I also was able to check "always allow", then I successfully revoked this authorization). So it's definitively a problem on my laptop side.

I found something weird too, I have two ADB installed, one in `${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/adb` and another in `/usr/local/bin/adb`. I tried repeating all above tests using explicitly `${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/adb`, yielding the same results.

Comment: are u already tried to another devices? or try using emulator

Comment: I just tried on another device, I get the `unauthorized` state instead. It seems like my laptop isn't asking the permission correctly (no mobile device showed the prompt asking for authorization)?

Comment: Try adb over wifi https://stackoverflow.com/a/69622418/236465

Comment: My phone doesn't show the pairing code when I turn "wireless ADB debugging" on (it doesn't show any dialogue).

Comment: I managed to re-authorize my phone using an USB-c to USB-c cable. That's a bit odd because I always used an USB-c to USB cable in conjunction with an USB to USB-c hub and never had a problem for several years.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One thing that worked for me was to change the USB hub I was connecting to on my MacBook M1. I had daisy chained two hubs and the device was connected to the second one.

So if your issue is with a USB hub, you can troubleshoot here as well.

Comment: Thank you! This was wasting so much time for me! Have 

Comment: Yeah, in the end my problem was similar, I had no USB-c to USB-c cable so I had to use the hub (because my mac only has USB-c ports). Removing the hub from the equation did solve the issue. Do you have a low tier hub or an expensive one? (mine is really one of the cheapest you can find on the market so I guess this might also play a role here?).

Comment: A pretty cheap one - about US $10 - with a USB-C connector stated to work on MacBooks.

Comment: For me I had my phone connected to my display's USB-hub. Reconnecting the phone to the USB hub had no effect. Ultimately what helped me was to reconnect the USB-C cable that goes from my display to my MacBook.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for bringing this loop. The problem appears with hubs that are not officially made or approved by apple. With an official(very expensive) hub it's working as expected. I hope this helps. (mine is a satechi usb-c hub)

Comment: The question is about adb for android. How is apple related to this?

Comment: "The question is about adb for android. How is apple related to this?" Because if it's connected to an Apple Mac, it can happen.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this as I was having the same issue.  In my case, I used a USB-C cable from a charger to connect and this was what was causing the device to get stuck in "authorizing" - I switched to a different cable and all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, third party cables work just fine with MacBook. What worked for me is to allow the device on my MacBook.

System settings -> Allow accessories to connect

Switch the option to "Ask every time". Reconnect the device, a prompt will popup, click allow.

Answer (score 0):

I did work, disable and enable USB debugging options on device, then disconnect and connect USB cable on device, after that should apper on mac and device a prompt to confirm connection.